# Android ClassNotFoundException android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

I have migrated my Android support libraries dependencies to AndroidX as per the documentation in the following official web page:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

After the migration I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap"
```

My gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.app.app.app"

        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.10'

    // Support
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    // Firebase
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

    // Misc
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.15'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please note that I have the following line:

```
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
```

If removed I will have this other problem:

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.*.*
```

I have start (*) the packages and classes changes on each compile:

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver
```

Comment: add v4 dependency also

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @SumitSaurabh Yes, I just revert back to support libraries. :(

Comment: @malhobayyeb so you removed the androidx?